# Regex capture numbers based on preceding text

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Consider the following text:

```
one="ambience: 5 comments:xxx food: 4 comments: xxxx service: 3 
comments: xxx" 

two="ambience: 5 comments:xxx food:   comments: since nothing to eat
after 8 pm service: 4  comments: xxxx "

three="ambience: it is a 5 comments:xxx food: a 6   comments: since nothing to eat
after 8 pm service: a 4  comments: xxxx "
```

for string one

```
    re.findall(ur'(ambience|food|service)[\s\S]*?(\d)',one,re.UNICODE)
    [('ambience', '5'), ('food', '4'), ('service', '3')]
```

for string two the result is

```
[('ambience', '5'), ('food', '8'), ('service', '4')]
```

since this logic purely looks for the first digit after the specific text it is fairly misleading when rating is skipped intentionally or otherwise .

If the consecutive rating is missed how do i get regex return the rating as NaN ?

> ```
> [('ambience', '5'), ('food', 'NaN'), ('service', '4')]
> ```

I also have a variant using look-ahead and look-behind  anchors

```
re.findall(ur'(?<=food)[\s]*:[^\d]*([\d[.|-|\/|-]+)[^\d]*(?=comment[s]*[\s]*:)',one,re.UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple change in regex would do the trick

```
(ambience|food|service):[^\d:]*(\d*)
```

- `[^\d:]*` matches anything other than a `:` or digit

Example matching http://regex101.com/r/bM0gT2/1

Example usage

```
>>> re.findall(r'(ambience|food|service):[^\d:]*(\d*)', one)
[('ambience', '5'), ('food', '4'), ('service', '3')]
>>> re.findall(r'(ambience|food|service):[^\d:]*(\d*)', two)
[('ambience', '5'), ('food', ''), ('service', '4')]
>>> re.findall(r'(ambience|food|service):[^\d:]*(\d*)', three)
[('ambience', '5'), ('food', '6'), ('service', '4')]
```

Comment: thanks! this clearly looks simple  than the look-ahead and look-behind anchors. Ive added a third category that requires to ignore strings that come before the number. Ive tried re.findall(r'(ambience|food|service):[^\w](\d*)', three) but it dosent seem to work with all scenario

Comment: @dacw I have edited the answer. Hope its fine now :)